# Why am I getting a vertical bar at the end of an equation?

Tags: equations

I am using Overleaf to write an equation. This is the latex:

```
\begin{equation*}
P_{0}\equiv \mathbf{E}\left[ \left( X_{0}-\hat{X}_{0}\right) \left( X_{0}-%
\hat{X}_{0}\right) ^{\intercal }\right] =\mathbf{E}\left[ \left( X_{0}-%
\mathbf{E}\left[ X_{0}\right] \right) \left( X_{0}-\mathbf{E}\left[ X_{0}%
\right] \right) ^{\intercal }\right] \equiv Cov\left( X_{0},X_{0}\right) .
\end{equation*}
```

Why am I getting a vertical bar at the end of the equation? (right after the final `.`)

[image]

I thought this may be since the equation is exactly as wide as the page.

I tried splitting the equation in two lines and the bar disappears. Is there a way to keep everything on one line removing the vertical line?

Here is some more information about the document I am writing:

```
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,
    corpo=12pt,
    oneside,
    stile=standard,
    tipotesi=magistrale,
    numerazioneromana, % roman numbering for appendixes and preambles, up to Table of Contents
    openright,
    cucitura=7mm,
]{toptesi}

\begin{document}
% ...
\end{document}
```

Packages I am using:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[hyperref=true,backref=true,backend=biber,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=2,style=numeric,citestyle=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex} 

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}          
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}              
\usepackage{bm}                    
\usepackage{booktabs}            
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[
    toc,
    abbreviations,
    nonumberlist,
]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{url}     
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

Comment: You are not showing a complete code so we can only guess. My guess is that you probably have the option `draft` and a rather small value for `\overfullrule`.

Comment: Unrelated: mist of your `\left...\right` pairs are irrelevant here their scaling are not needed. Additionally have a look at `\DeclareMathOperator\Cov{Cov}` to define a proper `\Cov` command.

Comment: The most straightforward way to make a complete document from your extract is to add `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{amssymb}` at the beginning and `\end{document}` at the end. That works fine and doesn't show any vertical bar, so more information (that is some other short complete document) from you is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am using a template I found on Overleaf. I'll add some more information about it in the original post!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get no “bar”. But I get an “Overfull `\hbox`” message.

You can avoid it by properly writing the expression with no `\left` and `\right` that create too big delimiters and excess space.

It's probably better to split the long equation in parts, doing a favor to your readers who will see more clearly the steps.

```latex
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,
    corpo=12pt,
    oneside,
    stile=standard,
    tipotesi=magistrale,
    numerazioneromana, % roman numbering for appendixes and preambles, up to Table of Contents
    openright,
    cucitura=7mm,
]{toptesi}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}          
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}              
\usepackage{bm}                    
\usepackage{booktabs}            
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[
    toc,
    abbreviations,
    nonumberlist,
]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[
  hyperref=true,
  backref=true,
  backend=biber,
  maxbibnames=9,
  maxcitenames=2,
  style=numeric,
  citestyle=numeric,
  sorting=none,
]{biblatex} 

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
P_{0}
\equiv \mathbf{E}\bigl[(X_{0}-\hat{X}_{0}) (X_{0}-\hat{X}_{0})^{\intercal }\bigr]
=\mathbf{E}\bigl[(X_{0}-\mathbf{E}[X_{0}])(X_{0}-\mathbf{E}[X_{0}])^{\intercal}\bigr]
\equiv \operatorname{Cov}(X_{0},X_{0}) .
\end{equation*}

\begin{align*}
P_{0}
&\equiv \mathbf{E}\bigl[(X_{0}-\hat{X}_{0}) (X_{0}-\hat{X}_{0})^{\intercal }\bigr] \\
&=\mathbf{E}\bigl[(X_{0}-\mathbf{E}[X_{0}])(X_{0}-\mathbf{E}[X_{0}])^{\intercal}\bigr]\\
&\equiv \operatorname{Cov}(X_{0},X_{0}) .
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Do you really need all those packages? By the way, `hyperref` should go last. Particularly `geometry` sounds very strange with no option.

For the covariance operator, use `\operatorname{Cov}`; but if you use it several times, it's better to have

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}
```

in the preamble and to use `\Cov` in the document.

[image]